# Checking string validity

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, mysql

In one script, I am getting the exifdata out of 20000+ photos and videos in various formats.

As I'm extracting the creation date, it works in most cases, however exif data is as good as the device that wrote it and some files use non standard encodings hence when inserting in mysql, I end up with a few errors like

"ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect datetime value: 'Oct 4 ' for column `gphoto`.`pictures`.`genesis` at row 1"

I would like to check the "$genesis" variable in bash to make sure it mysql datetime compatible before inserting it.

`if [[ "$genesis" "isinformat" "2020-11-30 11:01:45" ]]; then sqlstuff...; fi`

I was thinking grep with a regex might be one efficient way with something like

`if [[ "$(echo "$genesis"|grep '^???$')" != "" ]]; then ... fi`

But I wonder

- What that regex might be
- Do I have to pipe or can it be done without spawning an extra process?
- Maybe there is a specific prebuilt function for that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not just let `sql` decide? Something like Try...Except: `sqlstuff ... || echo "Not SQL compatible: $genesis"` or check it with your sql database: e.g. something like `psql 'select '"$genesis"'::datetime' && sqlstuff`

Comment: because if the string is not compatible, then I replace it with current datetime before instering into mysql.  As there are over 20000 files, i'd find it more "elegant" if a grep could avoid me an extra 20000 queries!

Comment: Probably you want to validate the date with a calendar, not just test with a regular expression, these are two different thngs. For example `2019-02-29` is hard to be caught by a regexp as invalid date. Also we don't know what is the input, what is the "sql stuff", if you have a command that could get many arguments, to suggest a massive way for this, currently you present only an if statement per entry.

Comment: aha! great point! will add some checks on that too many thanks!!!
```date -d $(echo "$string"|sed -e 's!:!/!g') > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo yeah || echo nope``` seems to do fine
indeed, I present only one statement per entry, as it is how the script currently works: building the db from the files, so determining the data from each file one by one, and then write the record.

Answer (score 0):

`"^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\ [0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]$"`

seems to be working as a grep regex for my purpose, but there might be a cleaner way

as pointed out by thanasisp, this does not catch for impossible dates, hence the test with date -d

`if  [[ ! $(date -d $(echo "2015:12:12"|sed -e 's!:!/!g')) ]] &>/dev/null ; then echo "not right"; fi`

which fails differently, as it possibly accepts some times also: if passed "12:04:15" it accepts is as valid... which lead me to my final solution for date checking:

`if  [[ ! $(date -d $(echo "12:04:15"|sed -e 's!:!/!g')) ]] || [[ ! "12:04:15" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] &>/dev/null ; then echo "not right"; fi`

which in context gives:

```
mmedia=thispic.jpg
eexifdata=($(exiftool -f -n -p '$GPSLatitude,$GPSLongitude,$CreateDate,$ModifyDate' $mmedia 2>/dev/null|sed -e 's/,/ /g' -e 's!/!:!g'))
if  [[ ! $(date -d $(echo "${eexifdata[2]}"|sed -e 's!:!/!g')) ]] || [[ ! "${eexifdata[2]}" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] &>/dev/null ; then # if date format is not acceptable
    eexifdata[2]="${eexifdata[3]}";eexifdata[3]="${eexifdata[4]}"; # then swap one position (exif is weird sometimes)
    if  [[ ! $(date -d $(echo "${eexifdata[2]}"|sed -e 's!:!/!g')) ]] || [[ ! "${eexifdata[2]}" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] &>/dev/null ; then # if issue persists
        eexifdata[2]="$(date +%Y:%m:%d)" # set current date
        eexifdata[3]="$(date +%H:%M:%S)" # set current time
    fi
fi
```